# Macbook Pro Late 2016 Monitor Flicking when using Viber video

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video

I have the latest Macbook Pro 2016 with the touchbar.

My setup is:

AMD Radeon Pro 450
2,6 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

When I make a **viber video call** if I move any window around the screen the monitor is flicking. Strangely, it is not the Viber window or the video flicking but the whole screen. The colours are trembling and the windows seem to be broken/have a delay while moving them around the screen.

I already returned a Macbook Pro 2016 to Apple because of that and also because it had some other issues with the graphic card. The new one that they gave me has exactly the same behavior as the one that I returned.

Way to reproduce it:

1. Install the latest Viber
2. Open Viber and do a video call (cameras ON from both sides)
3. During the Video call move around the screen some Finder or other applications windows.

Is it a general problem of the Hardware? Can one application (Viber) have such big impact to the graphics output and besides its own window affect the output of the whole screen?

With Skype video everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like GPU driver issues or application issues where the developers of the fiber app can fix things. Tons of libraries make hardware assumptions and might need to be updated for the new Apple hardware and GPU.

if this is something you can easily reproduce on new hardware, the chances of Apple or vibes fixing it are high. Unless you don't need the latest GPU and can exchange for the non touchbar Mac - I'd work with software side to get the bugs addressed even though that can be slow and frustrating and sometimes opaque as companies typically shield engineering staff from users with bugs to report.